# Передача структуры через HRF24L01 в системе Умный Дом

Tags: c, arduino, struct

Появилась нужда в передаче структури через модуль NRF24L01 на Arduino, и тут же появились новые проблеми. Попытаюсь вкратце объяснить:

Проект представляет собой два модуля из системы `Умный Дом`:

1. Главный модуль который общаеться с сервером по интернету, и в обязаности которого входит связь между модулями дома и сайтом на котором происходит управление ими.
2. Собственно один из модулей системи (дальше именуем как Реле).

Далее привожу часть кода программы главного модуля:

Объявление структуры в главном модуле (на Реле аналогичная)

```
typedef struct {
  float value;
  char mKey[11];
  char type[20];
} Message;
```

Проверяем не пришло ли чего от Реле

```
  if (radio.available()){
    Message sensor;
    radio.read(&sensor, sizeof(sensor));
    DataSendToServer(sensor.value, sensor.mKey, sensor.type);
  }
```

Проверяем нет ли команди от сервера к модулю

```
if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
        client.print( "GET /data.php?");
        client.print("uKey="+uKey);
        client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
        client.print( "Host: " );
        client.println(server);
        client.println( "Connection: close" );
        client.println();
        client.println();
        delay(200);
        while (client.available()) {
          int dataCount = client.available();
          for (int i = 0; i < dataCount; i++) {
            char c = client.read();
            if (c == '&') {
              String module = "";
              for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
                char mName = client.read();
                module += mName;
              }
              char cNext = client.read();
              cNext = client.read();
              String value = "";
              do {
                value += cNext;
                cNext = client.read();
              } while (cNext != '#');
              cNext = client.read();
              String type = "";
              do {
                type += cNext;
                cNext = client.read();
              } while (cNext != ']');
              DataSendToModule(value.toFloat(), mKey, mType);
            }
          }
        }
        client.stop();
        client.flush();
      }
      else {
       client.stop();
      }
```

Функция отправки данных от Реле к серверу

```
void DataSendToServer(float value, char module[11], char type[20]) {
  bool sucsess = 0;
  while (!sucsess) {
    if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
      client.print( "GET /data.php?");
      client.print("Type=");
      client.print(type);
      client.print("&moduleKey=");
      client.print(module);
      client.print("&Value=");
      client.print(value);
      client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
      client.print( "Host: " );
      client.println(server);
      client.println( "Connection: close" );
      client.println();
      client.println();
      client.stop();
      client.flush();
      sucsess = 1;
    }
    else {
      client.stop();
      delay(100);
    }
  }
}
```

Функция отправки данных от сервера к Реле

```
void DataSendToModule(float value, char mKey, char mType) {
  Message sensorSend = {value, mKey, mType};
  radio.stopListening();
  radio.openWritingPipe(pipe[0]);
  radio.write(&sensorSend, sizeof(sensorSend));
  radio.startListening();
}
```

Теперь привожу код самого Реле:

Объявляем структуру и переменные

```
char moduleKey[] = "XSzNOTANUs"; //ID модуля
int relay = 2;
float button = 0;
typedef struct {
  float value;
  char mKey[11];
  char type[20];
} Message;
```

Основной цикл программы

```
void loop() {
  if (radio.available()){
    Message sensorReceiv;   
    radio.read(&sensorReceiv, sizeof(sensorReceiv));
  }

  if (digitalRead(3) == HIGH) {
    button = !button;
    digitalWrite(relay, button);
    Message sensor = {button, "XSzNOTANUs", "Relay"};
    radio.stopListening();
    radio.openWritingPipe(pipe[1]);
    radio.write(&sensor, sizeof(sensor));
    radio.startListening();
  }
  delay(200);
}
```

Теперь в чем сложности:

Собственно передача структури от Реле к главному модулю и последующая отправка на сервер проходит без проблем, но вот когда пытаюсь от сервера передать команду Реле, ничего не получаеться. Кто заметил то уже понял что главний модуль считывает команду от сервера записывая ее в строку, а для отправки структури нужен массив, я уже по всякому питался это переделать, также и конвертировать пробовал, и даже питался команду считивать не в строку, а прямо в массив следующим способом:

```
      char module[11];
      for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        char mName = client.read();
        module[x] = mName;
      }
      char cNext = client.read();
      cNext = client.read();
      String value = "";
      do {
        value += cNext;
        cNext = client.read();
      } while (cNext != '#');
      cNext = client.read();
      char type[20];
      do {
        int i = 0;
        type[i] = cNext;
        cNext = client.read();
        i++;
      } while (cNext != ']');
```

Но почти всегда ошибка `invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char'` и я никак не могу понять как сделать правильно. А вот если прямо указать данные структуры `Message sensorSend = {value, "XSzNOTANUs", "Relay"};` то тогда все работает прекрасно, но вот мне так не подходит так как идентификатор модуля и эго тип всегда может быть разным. Необходима именно подстановка данных.

Помогитееее!!!!

Comment: `char*` - это тип указателя на строку символов типа `char`.

Comment: **ошибка invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char'** - укажите КОНКРЕТНО на какую строку кода ругается компилятор.

Comment: Проблема была в части где я считывал данные от сервера записывая их в строку, после этого передавал в функцию для отправки к Реле `void DataSendToModule(float value, char mKey, char mType)` где принять их нужно было в виде массива, и из них объявить структуру `Message sensorSend = {value, mKey, mType};`, вот при объявлении компилятор и ругался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена! Как оказалось суть была в не правильном объявлении массивов для структуры, Привожу работающий код программы:

После получения данных от сервера на главный модуль, и перед передачей их функции отправки к Реле, делаем конвертацию строки в массив

```
char mKey[module.length()+1]; //Объявляем массив с длиной равной количеству символов строки с идентификатором модуля + 1
module.toCharArray(mKey, module.length()+1); //Конвертируем строку в массив с указанием количества символов + 1
char mType[type.length()+1];
type.toCharArray(mType, type.length()+1);
DataSendToModule(value.toFloat(), mKey, mType); //Отправляем данные функции
```

В функции отправки данных к Реле объявляем структуру и отправляем

```
void DataSendToModule(float value, char mKey[11], char mType[15]) {
  Message sensorSend; //Объявляем структуру
  sensorSend.value = value; //Вносим значение
  strcpy(sensorSend.mKey,mKey); //Копируем массыв mKey в массыв структури
  strcpy(sensorSend.type,mType); //Копируем массыв mType в массыв структури
  radio.stopListening(); 
  radio.openWritingPipe(pipe[0]);
  radio.write(&sensorSend, sizeof(sensorSend));
  radio.startListening();
}
```

Как оказалось все заработало благодаря функции `strcpy()`, а еще оказалось что мне еще очень много предстоит узнать о программировании языком С, а то я не до сих пор не понимаю почему без нее не работало и почему теперь работает :D

Кстати если у кого-то есть какие-то соображения как это можна сделать компактнее или может правильнее - очень рад буду услышать :D